# Definite integral $\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-a t} \log(t)\log(1+t)\,dt$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, special-functions

Is there a closed-form expression (possibly in terms of special functions) for the integral:
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-a t}\log(t)\log(1+t)\,dt,
$$
where $a>0$?

Comment: Have you tried complex integration? Take a look at this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_contour_integration

Comment: What would be the contour of integration here though?

Comment: Does the integral converge?

Comment: There is a closed form in terms of [$\gamma$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant), $\pi$, the [exponential integral function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ExponentialIntegral.html), [incomplete gamma function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/IncompleteGammaFunction.html), [Meijer G-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/MeijerG-Function.html), and hypergeometric functions. (Courtesy of Mathematica)

Comment: How did you get Mathematica to yield this closed form? I tried the following code Integrate[Exp[-a*t]*(Log[t]*Log[t + 1]), {t, 0, Infinity}, 
 Assumptions -> a > 0] but to no avail.

Comment: If I remember correctly, integrating by parts once makes the remaining integral tractable (at least for Mathematica). I used $\mathrm{d}v=e^{-at}\,\mathrm{d}t$ and $u=\log(t)\log(1+t)$.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what was also suggested [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/111714/definite-integral-closed-form-expression).